# Where is glcorearb.h supposed to come from, and where is it supposed to live in Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opengl, glfw

I am trying to build [jpeg_gpu](https://github.com/negge/jpeg_gpu), and the current Visual Studio error is "Cannot open 'GL/glcorearb.h' ".

I can find the file 'glcorearb.h' online at [khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/api/GL/glcorearb.h), but I'm not entirely sure if I am supposed to just fetch this one file, or if it's supposed to be installed as part of some other library. It doesn't seem to come as part of GLFW or GLEW.

- What is the most sensible way to obtain glcorearb.h? On its own, or as part of a larger library?
- If it should be downloaded on its own, where is the most sensible place for it to live on a Windows machine for Visual Studio to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khronos is the official group for OpenGL matters. They publish the headers.

People at GLFW, GLEW, VS, or whatever, *download* the headers and incorporate in their code. Sometimes they do some small changes, mainly for 32/64 bit types or compiler adjustments.

If you compare `glext.h` and `glcorearb.h` you will see that the later doesn't include any stuff for OGL before 3.2, while the `glext.h` contains all. So, general libs (like GLEW) will provide and use `glext.h` instead of `glcorearb.h`.

If your code requires `glcorearb.h` then just fetch it from Khronos and put it in the same folder where `glext.h` is.